# In perforce, how do I list source file of a pending integrate?

Tags: perforce, perforce-integrate

I have a pending changelist open with several integrated files. Is there a way to list where (perforce path and revision) these files were integrated from? I'd like to double check that they were integrate from the correct place before submitting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To list unresolved integrations, use 'p4 resolve -n'.

To list resolved but unsubmitted integrations, use 'p4 resolved'.

Since you mention you're getting ready to submit, you've probably already resolved the integrations, so use 'p4 resolved'.

Comment: Tolli doesn't seem to be asking about resolving files.

Comment: 'p4 resolved' is the correct command to get this information. All integrations require resolution; integrate is how you pick the files to open, but resolve does the hard work of deciding what the final content is. p4 resolve and p4 integrate are like chocolate and peanut butter; they belong together.

Answer (score 3):

You can check if the file is a Lazy Copy (branched files are lazy copies).
Run `p4 fstat -Oc` on the file and check the `lbrFile` output, it will show you from where this file was integrated.

Also take a look:
http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/How-to-Identify-a-Lazy-Copy-of-a-File